# Android: unable to update my contacts through programming

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have written the code for simple update.I am able to insert and delete  the data from the the contacts of my AVD but when I want to update the data,its not updating.

here is my sample code:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
            String rawContactInsertIndex = (Integer.toString(ops.size()));

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withSelection( Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" , new String[] { rawContactInsertIndex })                        
                    .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, firstname)
                    .withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, lastname) 
                    .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, firstname)
```

can any one help? I am stuck here.

Comment: did U added permission in you manifest.xml for WRITE_CONTACTS Allows an application to write (but not read) the user's contacts data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, your `.withSelection(Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{rawContactInsertIndex}` is going to perform an update on **all** data columns where the `Data.CONTACT_ID` column has the value `0`. This includes phone numbers, addresses etc. etc.

Fortunately, there's no such contact apparently, because you'd f-ck that contact up **royally**.

To start, you should fetch the correct `CONTACT_ID` and do some work on your selection, i.e. do a selection on the `Data.MIME_TYPE` also.

```
contactId = Fetch the correct row identifier of the contact you want to update.

ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + Data.MIME_TYPE + "=?",
        new String[]{contactId, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
    .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, firstName)
    .withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, lastName)
    .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, givenName).build());
```

Also, are you sure you should be updating on `CONTACT_ID`? Consider using `RAW_CONTACT_ID`.